# Date time doesn't show correctly in qTranslate

Tags: date-time, plugin-qtranslate

I've used qTranslate to enable multiple languages on site. It works fine except for date-time for english language. Here are screenshots:

Serbian:
[image: serbian]

English:
[image: english]

Languages settings looks like:
[image: serbian edit]

[image: english edit]

How to fix this?

Comment: I think this plugin is not using wordpress language translation function <?php _e("my data"); ?>

Comment: Ok. Then I sould remove formatting from last image (I mean %A %B %e%q, %Y).

Comment: No not like that find function which display date and use _e();

Comment: You want to tell me that I edit qTranslate code?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ajay. The plugin isn't using __()/_e() function